# longtable, footnote, m type and arydshln

Tags: footnotes, longtable, arydshln

The longtable package allows to use footnote inside a longtable, as in this MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,longtable}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{m{1cm}|m{2cm}}
\footnote{Footnote}&\\
\hline
    \footnote{Footnote}&\\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

However, if I use also the arydshln feature, it does not work

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,longtable,arydshln}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{m{1cm}:m{2cm}}
\footnote{Footnote}&\\
\hdashline
    \footnote{Footnote}&\\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

In this case I need to insert at least a `p` column, but I don't want, because a |p colum takes place

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,longtable,arydshln}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{m{1cm}:m{2cm}|p{0cm}|}
\footnote{Footnote}&&\\
\hdashline
    \footnote{Footnote}&&\\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Any idea to solve this problem ?

Comment: I have send an email to the package author. He will look on it this week-end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version 1.72, now on CTAN, solve the issue. http://www.ctan.org/pkg/arydshln/